# How can I make a background transparent using css?

Tags: html, css

How can I add a background image to an element and make it transparent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS doesn't provide a way to add translucency to just a background image.

You can use the `opacity` property to make the *entire* element (content and children included) translucent.

You can use `rgba()` colour values to make a plain background translucent.

If you want a translucent background image, your best bet is to edit the image itself (and save it in a format that supports translucency, such as PNG).

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean the `alpha()` and `opacity()` property?
Take a look here http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp